# Mail not send through gmail id to gmail id in my server

Tags: php

I am using mail function for sending mails. It's working fine when I send mail from  Gmail ID to web mail and vice-versa but it's not working when I change it to Gmail ID to Gmail ID. Below is code which i found it in google.

```
$subject = 'subject';
$message = 'message';
$to = 'user@gmail.com';
$type = 'plain'; // or HTML
$charset = 'utf-8';

$mail     = 'mobisheer433@gmail.com';
$uniqid   = md5(uniqid(time()));
$headers  = 'From: '.$mail."\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-to: '.$mail."\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: '.$mail."\n";
$headers .= 'Message-ID: <'.$uniqid.'@'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\n";
$headers .= 'Date: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time())."\n";
$headers .= 'X-Priority: 3'."\n";
$headers .= 'X-MSMail-Priority: Normal'."\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary="----------'.$uniqid.'"'."\n\n";
$headers .= '------------'.$uniqid."\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/'.$type.';charset='.$charset.''."\n";
$headers .= 'Content-transfer-encoding: 7bit';
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
echo 'sucess';
```

Comment: What is a "Gmail ID"? You mean an email address at the "gmail" email service?

Comment: yes, it's a email address.